# Images not displaying on iOS CSS/HTML/Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a problem with image display on Iphone 6. Images are not loading on phone
 on Windows and android is working fine. I am using bootstrap as framework..
I identified that when i put imige in **img** tag is working on iOS

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/9bc549d82c.js"></script>
</head>


<div class="head">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 box">
          <p class="text-center" id="logo">
              Codence <i class="fa fa-heart-o " aria-hidden="true" id=""></i>
          </p>
          <span id="line"></span>
          <p class="lead text-center">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary" id="button">Learn more</a>
          </p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

.head{
height: 100vh;
background: url('../img/pexels-photo-234527.jpeg') repeat fixed 100%;
background-size: cover;
margin: 0 auto;
};
```

Comment: please include the relevant HTML in the question

Comment: Add space character before `repeat`.

Comment: HtML added. Thanks

Comment: I got the solution, background image in css should not have fixed attribute and is working on iOS